# SainSmart 5V 4 Channel Relay momentary switch

Tags: arduino, relay, solid-state-relay

I am wanting to hook this relay up here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sainsonic.com](http://www.sainsonic.com/zen/albums/ebay/nichegeek/20-018-101/IMG_0058.JPG))</sub>

What I am wanting it to be hooked to (output) is the PWR and reset switch on a PC motherboard to act as a momentary switch:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hardwarezone.com](http://assets.hardwarezone.com/2009/img/data/articles/2004/1192/11-frontpanel-header.jpg))</sub>

I am also wanting to hook one of those relays up to the 5v USB power so that I can turn off a USB product when I put the relay on high (which does not connect anything to the USB out).

So I am thinking it would be hooked up like so:

http://www.june3rdsoftware.com/relayArduino.jpg

And here is the schematic:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sainsmart.com](http://www.sainsmart.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/500x500/b97a0c6c1d16e76f7464abfcbb6a0a8d/4/c/4channel-relay2.jpg))</sub>

Let me know if this is correct!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: *What i am wanting it to be hooked too (output) is the pwr and reset switch on a PC motherboard to act as a momentary switch:*

Comment: That's obviously what you want, and what you have drawn, so what is your question?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have updated my OP with a new relay board and additional question.

Comment: Voting to close - this is unanswerable as if there is a question here at all, it is one that depends on broken off-site links.

Answer (score 3):

According to the mfg page for the SSR board you're proposing to use, it is intended to switch 75-264V **AC**. It's very possible that it will not correctly switch the 3 - 5 VDC for the power/reset ports of your motherboard.

The good news is that there is a 99% chance that your motherboard is just using logic inputs with a pull-up resistor to 3.3V or 5V. If so, you can probably directly connect these to your Microcontroller I/O pins.

First, use a multimeter in DC amp mode (use the lowest scale you can set) and connect the leads across the PWR switch pair and then across the RESET switch pair. When you do this, you should see the motherboard respond as if the button was pressed (the amp meter is acting as a short circuit) and observe the amount of current registering on your meter. If you see less than ~4 ma, you should be good.

Next, switch your meter to DC volts and measure again across each pair of pins and verify that it reads 5 volts or less. Also, note which pin is positive and which is negative.

You can now wire it up. Connect your micro's ground to one of the two negative pins. Connect I/O pins to each positive pin.

You'll need to program the I/O pins to "open drain" and then you can write a 0 to the pin to "press the button" and 1 to "release the button".

Comment: I have updated my OP with a new relay board and additional question.

Comment: To use the new board, you'll also need to supply +5VDC to the JDVCC and VCC pins on the lower right.